# How do I add these? $\cos(2\pi50t)+2\cos(2\pi150t)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos(2\pi50t)+2\cos(2\pi150t)$$
Can these be further simplified?
What is the addition of this called? Trigo identity?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the question.  Did you intend the contents of the parentheses to be fractions?

Comment: Other than multiplying your integers together, that's about as simple as it gets.

Comment: that is just part of the equations. but the full expression is similiar, its the result of multiplication of 2 equations. So I'm wondering can I simply add them together? and become 3cos(2$\pi$200t)?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite expression into :

$\cos (100 \pi t)+2 \cos(300 \pi t)$

Now use Triple-angle formulae :

$\cos 3\theta=4\cos^3 \theta -3\cos \theta$